# How to get Ant in Apache to copy files every build

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build.xml

I'm using Eclipse and Ant in my development environment.

I've come across a problem

Here's part of my build.xml

```
<target name="deploy" depends="dist" description="deploy jar files">
    <!-- Deploy jar files on local Tomcat -->
    <echo>Deploying in ${tomcat_home}/webapps</echo>

  <echo>Copying JSP files from ${build_dir} to ${tomcat_home}/${ant.project.name}/$</echo>
  <copy todir="${tomcat_home}/webapps/">
   <fileset dir="${resources_dir}/" includes="**/*.jsp"/>
  </copy>
```

I change a file, then run an ant build - all the files and jars are copied to the right place on my server.

But the problem I have is, if I make another change quickly and then run Ant again, my files aren't copied.  Obviously Any is looking at the timestamp to see when I last updated the file.  If it matches the same minute, it doesn't update.

How can I force the file copying every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `overwrite="true"` to force Ant to always overwrite files.  But looking at [the manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html), I also found this interesting tidbit regarding the `granularity` attribute:

> The number of milliseconds leeway to give before deciding a file is out of date. This is needed because not every file system supports tracking the last modified time to the millisecond level. Default is 1 second, or 2 seconds on DOS systems. This can also be useful if source and target files live on separate machines with clocks being out of sync. *since Ant 1.6.2.*

You could try experimenting with this to see if it helps.